# Python[Pandas,Tkinter] Can't read excel file path from askopenfilename

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, tkinter

i try to get the excel path from Tkinter with askopenfilename.
After the get path and read excel by pandas.
found error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File  "C:\Users\Pe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
   File C:/Users/Pe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Project/GUI.py", line 23, in select_file
     read_excelr()
   File "C:/Users/Pe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Project/GUI.py", line 26, in read_excelr
     df=Pds.read_excel(xlsx) NameError: name 'xlsx' is not defined
```

could you help me for the method to read excel?
thx

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import pandas as Pds

##### create the root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Read Excel')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('750x150')

lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text="Input Excel File")
lbl1.grid(column=0,row=0)

def select_file():
    filetypes = (('All files', '*.xlsx'),('text files', '*.txt'))
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(title='Open a file',initialdir='/',filetypes=filetypes)
    showinfo(title='Selected File',message=filename)
    lbl2['text']=(filename)
    print(filename)
    xlsx = Pds.ExcelFile(filename)
    read_excelr()
    
def read_excelr():
    df=Pds.read_excel(xlsx)
    print(df)
##### open button
open_button = ttk.Button(root,text='Open a File',command=select_file)
open_button.grid(column=1, row=0)
##### Text edit
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text='None')
lbl2.grid(column=2,row=0)

##### run the application
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to pass your `xlsx` variable from the `select_file()` function to the `read_excelr()` function as an argument.

Comment: thx a lot MattDMo. your answer help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "xlsx" is just a local variable, it only works in the specific function. You can pass xlsx to `read_excelr` function. This is the modified code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import pandas as Pds

##### create the root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Read Excel')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('750x150')

lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text="Input Excel File")
lbl1.grid(column=0,row=0)

def select_file():
    filetypes = (('All files', '*.xlsx'),('text files', '*.txt'))
    filename = fd.askopenfilename(title='Open a file',initialdir='/',filetypes=filetypes)
    showinfo(title='Selected File',message=filename)
    lbl2['text']=(filename)
    print(filename)
    xlsx = Pds.ExcelFile(filename)
    read_excelr(xlsx)
    
def read_excelr(xlsx):
    df=Pds.read_excel(xlsx)
    print(df)
##### open button
open_button = ttk.Button(root,text='Open a File',command=select_file)
open_button.grid(column=1, row=0)
##### Text edit
lbl2 = tk.Label(root, text='None')
lbl2.grid(column=2,row=0)

##### run the application
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Amazing. that's great. I still don't understand. do you mind, where i can read for more?

Comment: I mean i check at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html ,I still don't understand. and your answer help me a lot for my purpose.